# Div Background Overflow

Tags: css

When a div overflows body, body background color also overflows. Is this defined in the CSS spec somewhere? I could not find it.

When I inspect the elements in debugger, the body area seems as it should be but its background extends anyway.

Below you can find a sample code:

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: fuchsia;
}
#bar {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Comment: #bar div overflows the body.

Comment: You mention an element overflowing an outer `<div>` but you have `body > div` in your example. There is no _outer `div`_. What you are seeing doesn't happen if you have `div > div` instead of `body > div`.

Comment: @hungerstar You are right, I editted the question.

Comment: You just want to know *why* is it so and don't want to change current behavior or *how* to change this behavior?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov I just want to find out if it is defined anywhere in the specs. I think it is kind of an odd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The `<body>` is the ultimate parent of all the content (including every element) in the document.

Consequently, no child element within `<body>` can extend beyond the limits of `<body>`.

So if you give any element a `width` that is wider than the current `width` of `<body>`, the document `<body>` will automatically expand to contain it.

Comment: But the width of body seems to be narrower than its content as confirmed by several methods including inspecting it via the Chrome development tools and the getComputedStyle method. It looks like its width is not rearranged as to include the content but rather its background  overflows.

Comment: @JohnL. As far as I know, `body` is special element and its `width:100%` is always equal to `viewport-width` which means that other direct child-elements in the body with `auto-width` and `width:100%` will also take `viewport-width` as value during calculation. Right overflow of the body won't affect calculation (viewport is still the same). I'm sure that's the way how it works (happened to me a lot of times) but can't say is it meant to be this way, so don't take my word on this one. I guess it's documented somewhere, I haven't found it yet.